# How to get padding recognized on right side of a table in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, css-tables

In this tiny example, would you please tell me how to get the padding to be recognized on the right of the table in Firefox? The padding appears in Chrome but not Firefox.

Thank you.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 width: 175px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>

<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2 why no padding on right in Firefox?</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

</div>
```

Since was already using flexbox on the container holding the table, did the following which works in both Firefox and Chrome.

```css
table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

div.flexrow {
 display: flex;
 flexflow: row nowrap;
 overflow-x: scroll;
 width: 175px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 padding: 20px 0;
}

div.spacer {
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexrow">
  <div class="spacer"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Column 1</td>
          <td>Column 2 why no padding on right in Firefox?</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can work around like this: (1) change `div` styling to `padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;` (2) Add another `td` as `<td class="right-pad-col"></td>`, this will work as a padding on right, (3) the style `.right-pad-col { border: none; padding: 0px 10px; }`

Comment: @prasad Thank you. I thought a transparent table border on the left and right would work, too, but it removes the td borders when using border-collapse.